# How to display icon in ListView in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, listview, imagelist

Can you help me to display icon view from the files i get from a directory

Here is my code.

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SearchDir("g:\")
    End Sub

    Public Sub SearchDir(ByVal sDir As String)
        Dim fil As String

        Try
            For Each dir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)
                For Each fil In Directory.GetFiles(dir, " *.doc ")
                    ListView1.Items.Add(fil)
                Next
                SearchDir(dir)
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

this gives me a result, but in form of string displaying its path

Comment: You have used the `ImageList` tag on your question but there's no sign of an `ImageList` in your code and you haven't mentioned it in your question. It seems like you have fair idea of what you need to do but you haven't bothered to do any research on it and would rather we just do it for you. That's not how this site works. The documentation for the `ListView` class even includes a code example that uses `ImageLists`. You need to make an effort for yourself first.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you should not be adding items to a `ListView` one by one like that. As the documentation states, the preferred option is create all the items first and then add them all with a single call to `AddRange` but, if you are going to do it one by one, you need to call `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` before you start and after you finish respectively.

Comment: Thanks @jmcilhinney. I search for Imagelist, but i cannot figure out how to pass to it. That is why i am hoping someone can show me how it is done. Sorry I am newbie in vb.net

Comment: Then you really haven't looked because I know for a fact that there are examples on the web. There's no evidence of any effort in your code and you posted a few minutes after I did, so you haven't tried since then. If you just spend a minute or two "trying" and then give up then you're not really trying.

Comment: I just searched for "vb.net imagelist listview" and the first result was a question on this very site with an accepted answer that shows use of a `ListView` with an `ImageList`. That took me a few seconds to find. I repeat, you have not actually tried to solve your own problem.

Comment: Thanks for your "PRO" programming comments. No further answer needed PRO

Comment: @jmcilhinney _the preferred option is create all the items first_ that's very interesting. Thanks for sharing that. I looked through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview?view=netcore-3.1) documentation and didn't see mention of this. Do you have a link to the doc you read?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer, [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview) mentions `AddRange`, `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate`. It doesn't specify that using `AddRange` is preferred or recommended. I'm positive that I've read that in the past so they may have changed it. Regardless, the point is that calling `Add` repeatedly without `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` will redraw the control after adding each item. That will slow things down exponentially so is particularly bad as the number of items gets large.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks. I've always used the being and end updates. Was just interested to see other options. Thanks for your knowledge and contributions here! Always appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to add `ImageList` tool from Visual Studio Toolbox. Then select its properties and select the images you need to work with.

[image: ImageList Tool] [image: Configuration for ImageList]

After that, you need to use the corresponding given serial-wise IDs by `ImageList` in your `ListView` code as follows:

Declaration:

```
Private lView As ListViewItem ' listView's lView (not I-view)

lView = ListView1.Items.Add("Special iconic thing", 0) ' 0 = my icon ID in ImageList
```

You should get the similar to my output:

[image: Results]

Hope it works for you.